# Is $22/7$ an often used approximation for $\pi$?

Tags: education, approximation, math-history, pi, calculator

It is $\pi$-day and the internet is full of stories about $\pi$. [One story](http://www.cnn.com/2015/03/13/living/pi-day-things-to-know-feat/index.html) mentions that "an approximation -- $22/7$ -- is used in many calculations."

I have never actually used $22/7$ as an approximation for $\pi$ in a calculation ... or at least I don't have a memory of doing that.

My questions are

1. Is it true that today $22/7$ is an approximation that is used in many calculations? Are there, for example, any computers that use this approximation? Is $22/7$ in general (in the USA) often used in handcalculations that involve $\pi$?
2. I could imagine that before the widespread use of calculators, people would actually use $22/7$ as an approximation. Are there any historical examples of this?

Comment: See e.g. [the second line of this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Early_history) (Wikipedia), and references [2,3,4,5] within: *"Some Egyptologists have claimed that the ancient Egyptians used an approximation of π as 22/7 from as early as the Old Kingdom. This claim has met with skepticism."*

Comment: $22/7$ is not accurate enough for many modern purposes. But a very long time ago (read: millenia ago) it was frequently used as an approximation for $\pi$

Comment: $22/7 \approx 3.1428$ is a pretty bad approximation, and is at most used as a "back-of-the-envelope"-calculation.

Comment: Children in elementary schools in my country are taught that $\pi=\frac{22}7$...

Comment: I think that multiplying by $3.14$ by hand is faster and less error prone than multiplying by $22$ and then dividing by $7$, in general, and the error is about the same. So I never used $22/7$ by hand and obviously I never used it with a calculator.

Comment: @BigbearZzz To me that sounds like teaching children the concept of $\pi$ completely wrong from the very beginning.

Comment: @molarmass That's sad, isn't it? Go and ask, says, a high school student in Thailand, a smart one while we are at it, what is $\pi$. Chances are that he'll say that it's 3.14159265 or, in a sad case, $\frac{22}7$. 95% won't even know that it's the ratio of circumference over diameter.

Comment: The second question is a better fit for the [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site. Why don't you ask there?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I have flagged the question for reopening or migration.

Comment: Taking a second look at [the source of the "is used in many calculations" claim,](http://www.cnn.com/2015/03/13/living/pi-day-things-to-know-feat/index.html) in my opinion the statement is highly misleading. It gives the impression that $22/7$ is somehow more likely to be used than any other approximation, even today, which seems dubious even if we count only calculations "by hand". And considering the vast numbers of times that computers use approximations of $\pi$ every day, I would say practically all calculations that use any approximation of $\pi$ use far more accurate approximations.

Comment: Because you can't write down the value of $\pi = 3.1415926535...$.

Comment: Further to bigbear's comment, elementary (and middle) schools in some education systems design exercises such that the numbers/fractions within get cancelled out when interacting with $\frac{22}7.$

Answer (score 4):

The two better known rational approximations of $\pi$ are $\dfrac{22}7$ ($3$ correct figures) and $\dfrac{355}{113}$ ($7$ correct figures).

Personally I don't use them as I consider that they bring no real benefit over the straight decimal representations $3.14$ and $3.141593$.

---

These approximations did not arise by accident: they are the most efficient for a given magnitude of the denominator and can be retrieved from the theory continuous fractions.

Repeatedly that the inverse of the fractional part, and you get a sequence of integer parts

$$3,7,15,1,292\dots$$ so that

$$\pi=3+\frac1{7+\frac1{15+\frac1{1+\frac1{292+\cdots}}}}.$$

The first approximations can be drawn from this:

$$3,\frac{22}7,\frac{333}{106},\frac{355}{113},\frac{103993}{33102}\cdots$$

Answer (score 4):

For the first part of your question about whether computers use this approximation, I think the answer is generally "no." Most modern languages contain some sensible numerical constant in a library that has $\pi$ to machine precision.  The preference should be to use that.  Before that, like old-style Fortran, the "correct" way was to make your own constant using $\pi = 4 \tan^{-1} 1$. (Of course that doesn't mean that no one ever hand-coded 3.14 or 22/7 into their program, but there were always better, more accepted solutions.)

For the second part, there's a list of historical approximations at Wikipedia, for example.  It lists an old one going back to Archimedes:

> In the 3rd century BCE, Archimedes proved the sharp inequalities 223⁄71 < π < 22⁄7, by means of regular 96-gons (accuracies of 2·10−4 and 4·10−4, respectively).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Early_history

If true that shows it used as a bound.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: I observed that the amount of downvotes flying around in this thread is phenomenal. While I understand that the question may not be fully appropriate for this site, it still baffles me that people would throw downvotes everywhere just for that.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that 22/7 isn't used in actual calculations today. It's still the first of an interesting sequence of remarkably good approximations, in the following sense.

To approximate $\pi$ using tenths, just look at the beginning of the decimal expansion $\pi \approx 3.1$. You can be sure that you are within $1/20$ of the correct value. With $\pi \approx 22/7$ you can be sure that you are within $1/14 = 0.071428\ldots$, but in fact you're *much* closer than that: $\pi- 22/7 = 0.003069\ldots$. So $7$ is a very good denominator to use when looking for rational fractions near $\pi$. The next really good approximations are $333/106$ and $355/113$.

These good approximations come from the continued fraction for $\pi$ - see
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html .

Answer (score 1):

One mathematical use comes from the continued fraction expansion 
$$3 + \frac{1}{7 + \frac{1}{15 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{292 + \frac{1}{1 + \ldots}}}}}
$$

The "convergents" of this expansion are the approximations that you get by truncating the continued fraction. The first convergent is $3$, the next is $3 + \frac{1}{7} = \frac{22}{7}$, the next is $3 + \frac{1}{7 + \frac{1}{15}} = \frac{333}{106}$, and so on.

The mathematical importance of the continued fraction convergents $\frac{m}{n}$ of **any** real number $t$ is that they are very good approximations in a very precise sense: they are the only fractions such that 
$$\bigl|t - \frac{m}{n}\bigr| < \frac{1}{c \, n^2}
$$
where $c = \sqrt{5}$ (thanks to @Ian for the constant which I could not dig out of my brain at the right moment).

Comment: $c=\sqrt{5}$ (the upper bound is attained when $t=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$).

Comment: Continued Fraction approximations are guaranteed to have $\left|r-\frac pq\right|\le\frac1{q^2}$ and if $\left|r-\frac pq\right|\le\frac1{2q^2}$, then $\frac pq$ is guaranteed to be a continued fraction approximation for $r$.

Comment: @robjohn Interesting addition, but the first part is not optimal, as the Hurwitz theorem referenced above shows. The second part is quite interesting, though: only the continued fractions can be below $\frac{1}{2q^2}$ but they are actually below $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} q^2}$.

Comment: @Ian: Consider $106^2\left|\pi-\frac{333}{106}\right|=0.9350557349$ Something is amiss.

Comment: @robjohn I seem to have misunderstood the Hurwitz theorem: it actually says that the $t$ in question must be irrational, and it only says that a subsequence of the continued fraction convergents satisfies that inequality. So for instance it holds for $355/113$ with $\pi$ but not for $333/106$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Check my previous comment, I misled you slightly by mistake.

Comment: @Ian: what can be said, is that $\frac1{c_{n+1}+2}\le q^2\left|r-\frac pq\right|\le\frac1{c_{n+1}}$ where $c_{n+1}$ is the next term of the continued fraction. I chose $(3,7,15)=\frac{333}{106}$ since the next term is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course computers don't use $\frac{22}{7}$ as an approximation for $\pi$.

But *people* often do, when they need a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation of something, don't want to pull out a calculator/computer, and only need a few significant digits of precision anyway.

Comment: Do people really use it? When I still took physics classes either I needed to guesstimate an order of magnitude and then $\pi = 3$, or I need a nontrivial amount of significant places and I used a calculator. And in mathematics $\pi = \pi$ of course. I cannot recall ever using $\pi \approx 22/7$.

Comment: I disapprove those downvotes.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I'm pretty sure I have used it, at least.

Comment: Why does this answer get so many downvotes?

Comment: @BigbearZzz No idea, but this question seems to be divisive.

Comment: @BigbearZzz: All part of my secret plan to earn the Peer Pressure badge, perhaps?

Comment: I guess the downvotes come from the fact that people expect some sort of source for the assertion. It's not a math question where you can prove without doubt that your answer is correct just by writing down a proof, it's a sociology/history/i-don't-know question... A bare assertion is useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not downvote, but do you have any sources on the use by *people* of $22/7$ as a approximation? As Najib says, I just don't have any memory of ever actually using the approximation.

Comment: @JohnDoe I will try to find a source for you, though I doubt I can find some good ones. Nevertheless, I can assure you that children in Thailand are taught that $\pi=\frac{22}7$. I believe that most elementary school teachers in my country don't even _know_ that $\frac{22}7$ is just an approximation...

Comment: The difficulty in getting a "good" reference for when people use $22/7$ is that almost all uses I have ever seen in print are in textbooks and exam papers written for children. It does show up in some on-line "math help" sites such as http://www.knowmia.com/watch/lesson/42759 or http://www.mrmaisonet.com/index.php?/Circumference-Video/Circumference-Of-A-Circle-Using-22/7-For-Pi.html -- one even uses "the fact that $\pi=22/7$": https://www.wyzant.com/resources/answers/90483/using_the_fact_that_pi_22_7_find_as_a_fraction_the_circumference_and_area_of_a_circle_with_diameter_4_5_cm

Comment: In which context did you use it?

Comment: @quid: I don't remember. Something back-of-the-envelope, such as getting a ballpark number for the Earth's radius remembering that its circumference is 40,000 km.

Comment: So would you still say that people *often* use the approximation?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Shrug. I suppose all I can say is that it's the one I use when I need a paper-and-pencil approximation of $\pi$, and I don't have reason to think that it's _rarely_ used for that purpose.

Comment: I would say this approximation is one that a great many people know and _have_ used. Some people continue to use it for "back-of-the-envelope" purposes (it's better than $3.14$, at least), but because the "back of the envelope" is (almost by definition) something you throw away soon after using it, we cannot reasonably expect that documentary evidence would exist if this usage were very frequent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe if one divides by it, as in this case, it is actually more convenient than some decimal approximation. (For multiplication I would typically go with 3 or 3.1 or 3.15 all of which are relatively easy to compute.at least approximate.)